# How to remove link's text from html table

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to extract the **plain text** in the html table (that is, I don't want to grab the information including **red arrow**),

However, I tried to get the plain text by **cell.text**, it will get the unnecessary hyperlinks' text

```
"\n            central tendency1 \n          "
```

I expected that I can get

```
"central tendency"
```

So I tried `cell.text.strip.downcase.gsub!(/\d/, "")`,

However the **gsub** method will also clear the information in the green rectangle.

Is there any way to grab the text in html excepting the **text of hyperlink** ?

here's the html [link](http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcprojtabl20140618.htm#t1p1f1) I need to parse

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the `html` snippet for the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the links before converting to text with nokogiri:

```
table = doc.css(".page table")[0]
table.css("a").each(&:remove)
```

Edit: Alternatively, you can have a regexp that only removes numbers at the end of a string and if they're preceded by a letter, which seems like it may work in this specific case but cannot be relied upon to work in similar cases:

```
cell.text.strip.downcase.gsub(/(?<=\w)\d$/, "")
```